# Pentaho HTTP-client - Calling a web-service from a base-URL with two-step verification security

Tags: pentaho

I have used the Pentaho-based "HTTP-Client" to extract the HTML code of a supplied website and used the jsoup .jar library to parse the HTML and retrieve specific nodes of information from the HTML code (please refer to [this website](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/130919-How-to-read-a-Webpage-and-save-it-locally-(by-step-quot-Modified-Java-Script-Value-quot-)/) for more information). This sequence of steps works perfectly for websites without authentication or websites with One-Time Password (OTP) authentication but does not work for websites with two-factor authentication.

Though I am not attempting to by-pass the two-factor authentication, I would like to know if I can supply the verification token (as supplied through a mobile phone app) as a temporary variable that I manually input into Pentaho. In this scenario, Pentaho would have to use the HTTP login, the HTTP password and the verification token to pass the two-factor authentication imposed by the website.

Could anyone please advise on how to pass a two-factor authentication in Pentaho (consdering the aforedescribed scenario)?